# Use CMake to set Debugging->Environment string for Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

Is there a command in CMake to set the value in Visual Studio when you right click on a project, go to Properties, then Debugging->Environment.

I like to put a string like this in that value:
PATH=C:/libs/vtk/bin/bin/$(Configuration);%PATH%

This allows me to maintain where DLLs are for a project on a project-by-project basis. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Support VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT in cmake projects](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/814664/support-vs-debugger-environment-in-cmake-projects.html).
You need to add the following CMake code fragment in your project CMakeLists.txt

```
if(WIN32)
    set_target_properties(chebyshev_polynomials_demo 
        PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT "PATH=%PATH%;$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:Qt5::Core>;"
    )
endif()
```

Comment: I receive the error " set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
  chebyshev_polynomials_demo "